# How to get username without domain

Tags: asp.net

In an aspx page I get the Windows username with the function `Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name`. This function returns a string in the format "domain\user".

Is there some function to only get the username, without resorting to the `IndexOf` and `Substring`, like this?

```
public static string StripDomain(string username)
{
    int pos = username.IndexOf('\\');
    return pos != -1 ? username.Substring(pos + 1) : username;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget about the @ format for domain + username: exampleuser@exampledomain.com. `Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name` may return the domain in this format depending on how the user was SSO'd.

Comment: See UPN under https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/user-name-formats

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I don't believe so. I have got the username using these methods before-

```
var user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User;   
var name = user.Identity.Name;

var slashIndex = name.IndexOf("\\");
return slashIndex > -1 
    ? name.Substring(slashIndex  + 1)
    : name.Substring(0, name.IndexOf("@"));
```

or

```
var name = Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;

var slashIndex = name.IndexOf("\\");
return slashIndex > -1 
    ? name.Substring(slashIndex  + 1)
    : name.Substring(0, name.IndexOf("@"));
```

Comment: Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name works just fine for a login form to get the logged in user's username on the domain when creating a login form that uses LDAP.  The rest require the windows auth pop up I believe.

Comment: Note this doesn't account for username@domain.com variant of domain + username as @nop points out below.

Comment: See UPN under https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/user-name-formats

Answer (score 62):

If you are using Windows Authentication. 
This can simply be achieved by calling `System.Environment.UserName` which will give you the user name only.
If you want only the Domain name you can use `System.Environment.UserDomainName`

Comment: @Robin V., do you know what happens if you use `runas` and the like?, my guess is that the System.Environment variables only reflect the logged in user, not the identity which runs the .NET process (might not be identical)

Comment: my app's running as me & this returns "iis pool" for me.  Pretty sure the question states aspx, I believe this would work in winforms though.

Comment: When are you using for example _runas_ command what you get is the name of currently logged user on a machine and not the user under the process is running.

Comment: In a published ASP.NET application, this property returns the name of the application pool account (such as Default AppPool).

Comment: All of the above comments are correct, can we get this answer flagged as misleading and inaccurate? I wasted time trying it when it's not the identity at all...

Answer (score 24):

Getting parts[1] is not a safe approach. I would prefer use LINQ .Last():

```
WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
if (windowsIdentity == null)
    throw new InvalidOperationException("WindowsIdentity is null");
string nameWithoutDomain = windowsIdentity.Name.Split('\\').Last();
```

Comment: This approach would give the wrong result though if the `Name` did not contain a backslash for some reason (e.g. Workgroup?)

Comment: @MattWilko: I know this is an old post, but FYI (in case anyone else is curious) this approach will work even when the domain isn't present. i.e., "domain\userid" and "userid" will both return as "userid", at least it did when I tested it.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using .NET 3.5 you could always create an extension method to the WindowsIdentity class that does this work for you.

```
public static string NameWithoutDomain( this WindowsIdentity identity )
{
    string[] parts = identity.Name.Split(new char[] { '\\' });

    //highly recommend checking parts array for validity here 
    //prior to dereferencing

    return parts[1];
}
```

that way all you have to do anywhere in your code is reference:

> Request.LogonUserIdentity.NameWithoutDomain();

Answer (score 1):

```
static class IdentityHelpers
{
    public static string ShortName(this WindowsIdentity Identity)
    {
        if (null != Identity)
        {
            return Identity.Name.Split(new char[] {'\\'})[1];
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

If you include this code, you could then just do something like:

```
WindowsIdentity a = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
Console.WriteLine(a.ShortName);
```

Obviously in a web environment, you wouldn't write to the console - just an example...

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way of doing the same thing as the other answers:

```
var usernameWithoutDomain = Path.GetFileName(@"somedomain\someusername")
```

It is just unsafe as not checking for the @ variant of usernames.

Comment: Thank you for raising the different format for domains (@) - no other answer bothers to address the glaring issue in just checking for slash. We really need a utility method for this in .net...

Answer (score 0):

I was suggesting to use regexpes but they would be overkill.
[System.String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(VS.80).aspx) do the job.

```
string[] parts= username.Split( new char[] {'\\'} );
return parts[1];
```