# Extract username from DOMAIN\Username c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ldap

I have implemented an application that authenticates users against active directory using LDAP. Since users are being authenticated from different domains, they log in by `DOMAIN\UserName`. After being logged in, I capture the username by using `User.Identity.GetUserName()` however this, of course, returns `DOMAIN\UserName`. What I need to do here now is to extract the `UserName` from the string returned. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get username without domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330320/how-to-get-username-without-domain)

Comment: yes it is a duplicate.... Just realized that after posting the question. maybe I wasnt searching for the right thing. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about `User.Identity.GetUserName().Split('\\')[1]` ?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for  [`Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string FullName =  User.Identity.GetUserName();
string UserName = FullName.Substring(FullName.IndexOf("\\"));
```

(You might have to throw a `+ 1` right after `FullName.IndexOf("\\")`)

Answer (score 0):

```
public string RemoveDomain(string username)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username))
        return username;

    return username.Split('\\').Last();
}
```

This will handle null and username without domain name as well.

Usage:

```
var username = RemoveDomain("Domain1\\Username");
username = RemoveDomain("Username");
username = RemoveDomain(null);
```