# how to get current windows login user full name instead of domain name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows

i want to get current windows user full name not with domain name.
am using below code to get user name but its giving name with domainname.

string UserName = Request.ServerVariables["AUTH_USER"];

string a=System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

in above 3 statements am getting like APAC\san123.
but here i want my fullname.
here am using mvc with c#.

Comment: Does `Environment.UserName` not fit your requirements? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.username?view=net-5.0

Comment: Is the full name one of the items of data known to the identity system?

Comment: @ConnorTJ `Environment.UserName` would be the name of the account running the application (e.g. an IIS AppPool), not the client.

Comment: @MartinCostello ahh, please ignore my confusion, I must have misread the question, in that case, isn't this the same question answered in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/263853/13108684 or this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/330408/13108684

Comment: @ConnorTJ The OP is already using `User.Identity.Name`, it's part of the question. The actual question has been asked before, yes, I've just closed as a duplicate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the users full name from the active directory (using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement):

```
PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,Environment.UserDomainName);
string loginName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, loginName);
string userName = user.Name; //=user.GivenName + " " + user.Surname;
```

Comment: The one who downvoted this answer, please could you explain what is wrong with it?

Comment: Perfect Bro your Genius